# LINQ Group By and merge properties

Tags: c#, linq

```
private static void Main()
{
    var accounts = new List<Account>()
    {
    new Account { PrimaryId = 1, SecondaryId = 10 },
    new Account { PrimaryId = 1, SecondaryId = 12 }
    };
}

public class Account
{
    public int PrimaryId { get; set; }
    public IList<int> SecondaryIds { get; set; }
    public int SecondaryId { get; set; }
}
```

Suppose I have the above code, I would like to group by PrimaryId and merge SecondaryId into SecondaryIds.

For example:

```
// PrimaryId = 1
// SecondaryIds = 10, 12
```

How can achieve it?

I did this so far

```
var rs = accounts.GroupBy(g => g.PrimaryId == 1)
.Select(s => new Accounts 
{ PrimaryId = 1, SecondaryIds = new List<int>() { /*???*/  } });
```

Comment: Why does class Account have a list of SecondaryIds and a single SecondaryId? It'd perhaps be better, if this is the enduring storage for an account, to just have a list of SecondaryIds, and if there is only one secondary ID, put it in the list.. Like `new Accounts { PrimaryId = 1, SecondaryIds = new(){10} },`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

##### What I'd do, perhaps

LINQ `GroupBy` in its simplest form, takes a lambda that returns the Key that shall be grouped by. `.GroupBy(a => a.PrimaryId)`. It produces something like a "list of lists", where everything in the inner list has the same key.

If you did that grouping you could explore it like this:

```
var listOfLists = accounts.GroupBy(a => a.PrimaryId);

foreach(var innerList in listOfLists){
  Console.WriteLine("Key is: " + innerList.Key);

  foreach(Account account in innerList)
    Console.WriteLine("Sid is: " + account.SecondaryId);
}
```

So it's effectively put your Account objects into something like a `List<List<Account>>`, except the inner list has a `Key` property that tells you what common value (the PrimaryId) the accounts in the inner list all share

There's an extended form of GroupBy that takes a second argument of "what item, possibly from the original objects, do you want to put into the inner list?", and we could use that like this:

```
.GroupBy(a => a.PrimaryId, a => a.SecondaryId)
```

This would create something like a `List<List<int>>` because instead of the whole account object, it's just pulling the SecondaryId out and putting *that* in the inner list. This is fine because you can still get the PrimaryId from the `Key` and there isn't anything else in an Account

---

There's actually even another form of GroupBy with a *third* argument that will take each item in the resulting "list of lists" and allow you to do something with *that*..

```
.GroupBy(
  a => a.PrimaryId,     //derive the key
  a => a.SecondaryId,   //derive the innerList
  (key, innerList) => new Account { PrimaryId = key, SecondaryIds = innerList.ToList() }
)
```

You can think of this third argument as being like the `.Select()` you've put on the end of the groupby. It's slightly different, and perhaps a bit easier to use because of that clear separation between "the key" and "the list of things with that key"

So, the first argument `(key,` is the grouping key (the `PrimaryID`), and the second argument `innerList)` is the list of all the `SecondaryId`s with that grouping key. We can use these two bits of info to make a new `Account` object with the Primary and SecondaryIds set

---

I mentioned in the comments that it's weird to have a single SecondaryId and also a list of them in one object.. I know why you've done it, but if you wanted to drop the SecondaryId singular and just keep the list, the groupby would change slighty:

```
.GroupBy(
  a => a.PrimaryId, 
  a => a.SecondaryId.First(),   //take the only item
  (key, innerList) => new Account { PrimaryId = key, SecondaryIds = innerList.ToList() }
)
```

This would be capable of processing a single item list of secondary IDs, for example something like this:

```
var accounts = new List<Account>()
{
  new Account { PrimaryId = 1, SecondaryIds = new(){10} },
  new Account { PrimaryId = 1, SecondaryIds = new(){12} }
};
```

---

##### Taking a look at your attempt:

```
var rs = accounts.GroupBy(g => g.PrimaryId == 1)
.Select(s => new Accounts 
{ PrimaryId = 1, SecondaryIds = new List<int>() { /*???*/  } });
```

Doing `.GroupBy(g => g.PrimaryId == 1)` will group by an assessment of whether the PrimaryId is 1 or not. It won't *filter* anything to "just ID 1" - essentially anything that was PrimaryId 1 would go in one inner list, and everything else would go in another. The `Key` of the inner list would be a `bool`. If your accounts list only contained Account objects with Primary ID 1 then all would be fine. It'd go a bit haywire if it didn't

```
.Select(s => new Accounts 
{ PrimaryId = 1, SecondaryIds = new List<int>() { /*???*/  } });
```

Your GroupBy() with one argument has produced something like a `List<List<Account>>`, so it means `s` is the inner list. It's actually an `IGrouping<Account>` which is like a list of Account objects but with that extra Key property that tells you what all the items in the grouping have in common.

This means that, because this `.Select` is giving you `s` and `s` is a list of Account, and you want just the *SecondaryId* out of each account in that list, you need *another* Select, this time *on `s`* to pull just the SecondaryId out of each account within it:

```
.Select(s => new Accounts 
{ 
  PrimaryId = 1, 
  SecondaryIds = s.Select(acc => acc.SecondaryId)
});
```

and then you want to call ToList() on *that* Select

```
.Select(s => new Accounts 
{ 
  PrimaryId = 1, 
  SecondaryIds = s.Select(acc => acc.SecondaryId).ToList()
});
```

If I was doing that way I'd do:

```
.GroupBy(a => a.PrimaryId)
.Select(g => new Accounts 
{ 
  PrimaryId = g.Key, 
  SecondaryIds = g.Select(acc => acc.SecondaryId).ToList()
});
```

But the 3 argument GroupBy is a bit cleaner..

Comment: The 3-argument `.GroupBy()` was new to me, but I am definitely going to start using it. Genius.

Comment: It's definitely not helped by the documentation being crazy to read! I mean `GroupBy<TSource,TKey,TElement,TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,TKey>, Func<TSource,TElement>, Func<TKey,IEnumerable<TElement>,TResult>, IEqualityComparer<TKey>)` - c'mon Microsoft! How's a human supposed to make heads/tails of that..

Comment: Haha, true, it's intimidating! Luckily, though, they have provided an example for that specific [GroupBy overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-groupby-4(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-func((-0-2))-system-func((-1-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-2))-3)))).

Comment: Great explanation of GroupBy()!

Answer (score 3):

When using `.GroupBy()` followed by `.Select()`, you need to drill down one level inside your grouped items:

```
var rs = accounts
    .GroupBy(a => a.PrimaryId)
    .Select(gr => new Account {
        PrimaryId = gr.Key,
        SecondaryIds = gr.Select(account => account.SecondaryId).ToList()
    });
```

Comment: If you `string.Join` the ids I think yo have what OP wants.

Comment: @gert-arnold OP say they want to populate `SecondaryIds`, which is an `IList<int>` in the `Account` class. How do you achieve that using `string.Join( )`?

Comment: OK, I guess you're right, I was mainly looking at the output example.

Comment: When looking at the output example alone, I agree that your suggestion would make sense :+1: