# How to concatenate multiple rows list with same value into single row

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class called "Person".

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public string Hobby { get; set; }
}
```

I created a list with the following data:

```
List<Person> users = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person {Id= 1, Name = "Silva", Hobby = "Football" },
    new Person {Id= 2, Name = "Bob", Hobby = "Golf"},
    new Person {Id= 2, Name = "Bob", Hobby = "Tennis"},
    new Person {Id= 1, Name = "Silva", Hobby = "Sleeping"},
    new Person {Id= 3, Name = "Sue", Hobby = "Drinking"}
    new Person {Id= 1, Name = "Silva", Hobby = "Handball"},
    new Person {Id= 3, Name = "Sue", Hobby = "Football"},
};
```

Now I need to create a new list called "usersHobbies" that when called returns the following result.

```
Id    Name        Hobby 
1     Silva       Football, Sleeping, Handball   
2     Bob         Golf, Tennis
3     Sue         Drinking, Football
```

Comment: var results = users.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => new {Id = x.Key, Name = x.First().Name, Hobbies = string.Join(",", x.Select(y => y.Hobby))}).ToList();

Comment: Why are there multiple `Person` objects with the same `Id`? What happens if there are persons with same `Id` but different `Name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use [`GroupBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0) to achieve that. Group by `Id`, select the `Name` from the first group, use `string.Join()` to join the Hobbies into a single string:

```
var result = users.GroupBy(u => u.Id)  // group by Id
                  .Select(g => new     // select values
                  { 
                      Id = g.Key, 
                      Name = g.First().Name, 
                      Hobbies = string.Join(", ", g.Select(u => u.Hobby)) 
                  })
                  .ToList();
```

Output:

[image: result showing 3 rows]

If you want to return a new `Person` instead of an anonymous type, just update the `Select`:

```
 .Select(g => new Person
  { 
      Id = g.Key, 
      Name = g.First().Name, 
      Hobby = string.Join(", ", g.Select(u => u.Hobby)) 
  })
```

---

**Update** from your comment:

> is it possible instead of string.join() to return a list or array

Yes, it is. Using an anonymous type:

```
var result = users.GroupBy(u => u.Id)  // group by Id
                  .Select(g => new     // select values
                  { 
                      Id = g.Key, 
                      Name = g.First().Name, 
                      Hobbies = g.Select(u => u.Hobby).ToList() 
                  })
                  .ToList();
```

Which returns a `List<string>` for `Hobbies`.

Answer (score 0):

`.GroupBy()` has an override that lets you define a key selector, an element selector and the result selector ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-groupby-4(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-func((-0-2))-system-func((-1-system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-2))-3))))), which could suit your use case:

```
var result = users
    .GroupBy(
        u => new { u.Id, u.Name }, // key selector
        u => u.Hobby, // element selector
        (user, hobbies) => new Person { 
            Id = user.Id, 
            Name = user.Name, 
            Hobby = string.Join(", ", hobbies) })
    .ToList();
```

Here, `(user, hobbies)` are referencing the key selector and the element selector, respectively.

What happens is:

- the users are grouped into unique users based on the combination of `Id` and `Name` (key selector)
- the hobbies of each unique user are collected into an `IEnumerable<string>` (element selector)
- for each unique user, a `Person` object is created and populated with all of the users hobbies.

Comment: Shoutout to @caius-jard (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71037478/linq-group-by-and-merge-properties/71037824#answer-71037825)) for opening up my eyes to the 3-argument `.GroupBy()`.